How to manage serviceAccountKey expiration on apache camel?
I work on an Camel application with the Google PubSub Component. I have a route with an ErrorHandler(deadLetterChannel()) that works pretty well on common error, but i had a serviceAccountKey expiration which it does not throw any error.
For debugging my problem, i turn log level at "debug" level and juste launch my application to see logs.
My route connect Google PubSub to Google PubSub.
I have see in logs an error 400 with

""error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"Invalid JWT
Signature."".

I checked on PubSub admin pannel, that shows that my serviceAccountKey has expired. I thus generated a new one and reran my application: no more error.
I am thus looking for a method to catch this error (which is not interpreted as an error) and manage it.
